# Facebook Insights returning empty data array even though data points exist

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using this query:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/xxxxx/insights/post_stories_by_action_type?access_token=xxxxx&since=1451721599&until=1454313600
```

The two epoch dates will make the date range return 2016-01-01 - 2016-01-31. It is a bit wonky with the API determining that Jan 1's data is going to be the datapoint that `ends` on `Jan 2 08:00 GMT` which means in order to grab that inclusive I have to subtract 1 second at the end, hence the 599 not 600. But I digress.

Using the same query string but with different metrics (such as `page_impressions_by_paid_non_paid_unique`, `page_engaged_users`) I get the desired results. However `post_stories_by_action_type` just returns this:

```
{
  "data": [
  ],
  "paging": {...}
}
```

I manually ran an export from facebook insights with `post data` selected and the given date range and in the 3rd tab `Lifetime Post Stories by act...` of the `xls` file I see data. Lots of it too. Why does the API return nothing?

PS. The `access_token` I am using is an extended `page_access_token` for the page I am trying to get data from. It has `read_insights` and `manage_pages` permissions. It works fine for the other metrics.

EDIT:

If I query for the `post_id` instead of the page I get the individual result for that post. However given dozens of posts per month this would be incredibly inefficient to query individually. How do I get all that post data with preferably one query of the page object?

EDIT2:

It turns out I can grab what I want with `2.5/xxxxx?fields=posts{insights{values,name}}` which grabs all the insights for all the posts (can be limited with since&until params). However I cannot seem to only get the one insight I want. Suggestions?

Comment: It looks like you are querying the story object instead of the actual post. A story is different from a photo/ album. What type of object are you querying and comparing with ?

Comment: hi i have tried to get metrics insight the data returned is empty